# How to revoke permissions of a specific field in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.pagos
(
    condominio character varying(12) NOT NULL,
    id_unidad character varying(10) NOT NULL,
    fechapago date NOT NULL,
    montopago integer NOT NULL
)
```

A user:

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'user1';
```

I give permissions to it user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON pagos TO user1;
```

How I can Revoke all permissions (in this case only select) of user1 **in a specific field** of the table (like the montopago field) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions in SQL are additive, so you can never make exceptions of the kind "grant select on the whole table, but revoke it from one specific column". What you need to do is to revoke the permission you granted on the whole table and grant column permissions instead:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON pagos FROM user1;
GRANT SELECT (condominio, id_unidad, fechapago) ON pagos TO user1;
```